# select all rows based on max(cases) and min(date)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table covid, my table looks something like this:

```
location     | date     | new_cases | total_deaths | new_deaths
----------------------------------------------------------------
Afghanistan   2020-04-07    38             7             0
Afghanistan   2020-04-08    30             11            4
Afghanistan   2020-04-09    56             14            3
Afghanistan   2020-04-10    61             15            1
Afghanistan   2020-04-11    37             15            0
Afghanistan   2020-04-12    34             18            3
```

In this case, I want to get rows location based on max(new_cases),this is my query:

```
select a.*
from covid a
    join (
    select location, max(new_cases) highest_case
    from covid 
    group by location 
    ) b 
on a.location = b.location
and a.new_cases = b.highest_case
```

but I found the same location and max(case) values with the different date value, this is the result.

```
location     | date     | new_cases | total_deaths | new_deaths
----------------------------------------------------------------
Bhutan        2020-06-08    11           0              0
Bolivia       2020-07-28    2382         2647           64
Bonaire Sint  2020-04-02    2            0              0
Bonaire Sint  2020-07-15    2            0              0
Botswana      2020-07-24    164          1              0
```

Now, how can I get the values based on min(date), please give me advice for fix this, and the output should be like this:

```
 location     | date     | new_cases | total_deaths | new_deaths
----------------------------------------------------------------
Bhutan        2020-06-08    11           0              0
Bolivia       2020-07-28    2382         2647           64
Bonaire Sint  2020-04-02    2            0              0
Botswana      2020-07-24    164          1              0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function Max() to get max_cases (according to location) and then numbering rows (to fetch the min date) :

```
select location,date,new_cases,total_deaths,new_deaths from
(
--get min date with max_cases
select row_number()over(partition by location order by date)n,date,
location,new_cases,total_deaths,new_deaths
 from
   (
     select location,date,max(new_cases)over(partition by 
     location)max_case,new_cases,total_deaths,new_deaths from covid  --get max_case
   ) X
  where new_cases=max_case   --fetch only max case
)Y where n=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (location) c.*
from covid c
order by location, new_cases desc;
```

For the minimum date, use:

```
order by location, date asc;
```

Comment: I hoped to be faster than you, but was late again ;(  :thumbsup:

Comment: @Maciej Los, Same )